# Code not permanently deleting rows with specific string in df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Trying to permanently delete all rows that contain a given string. Tried this code, it runs but if you df.head() afterwards it doesn't show that it dropped.

```
df[df["column"].str.contains('text')==False]
```

Comment: Because you haven't assigned the filtered dataframe to anything. `df=df[df...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try assigning it to the df. Like:

> `df = df[df["column"].str.contains('text')==False]`